# How to fix "Ajax error with status error 500"?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Im send input data with ajax jQuery, but i get status erorr code 500, how to fix it to get status code 200? This code work in my localhost, but i want to hosting this code and i get this error, pls help me to fix it

This is my controller

```
private function insert(){
    $hasil = $this->model->insert($_POST['bulan'], $_POST['tahun'], $_POST['petugas']);
    return $hasil;
}
```

this is my Model code

```
public function insert($bulan, $tahun, $petugas){

    $sql10 = "SELECT bulan_tutupBuku, tahun_tutupBuku FROM tutupBuku;";
    $statement1 = $this->connection->prepare($sql10);
    $statement1->execute();
    $fetch1 = $statement1->fetchAll();
    $statement1->closeCursor();
    if (!empty($fetch1)) {
        foreach ($fetch1 as $fetch2) {
        }
    }
    if ($fetch2['bulan_tutupBuku'] === $bulan && $fetch2['tahun_tutupBuku'] === $tahun) {
        return "error";
    }
    else if(empty($bulan) || empty($tahun) || empty($petugas)){
        return "kosong";
    }else{
        $sql0 = "INSERT INTO tutupBuku(bulan_tutupBuku, tahun_tutupBuku, petugas) VALUES(:bulan, :tahun, :petugas)";
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql0);
        $statement->bindValue(':bulan',$bulan);
        $statement->bindValue(':tahun',$tahun);
        $statement->bindValue(':petugas',$petugas);
        $statement->execute();
        $fetch = $statement->fetchAll();
        $statement->closeCursor();
        return "success";
    } 
}
```

AND this is my Ajax code

```
  $("#simpan_user").click(function(){
    var data = {
        aksi    : "insert",
        bulan   : $("select[name='bulan']").val(),
        tahun   : $("input[name='tahun']").val(),
        petugas : "<?php echo $_SESSION['f658f7a22761210065c7ae4211aab09b'];?>"
    };

    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php?page=6a3b61f42cded56019b264080e226e40&kode=tutupBuku",
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        if (msg === 'success') {
          swal ( "Success" ,  "Berhasil Tutup Buku" ,  "success" );
          location.reload();
        }else if(msg === 'kosong'){
          swal ( "Oops" ,  "Inputan Masih Ada Yang Kosong !" ,  "warning" )
        }else if(msg === 'error'){
          swal ( "Oops" ,  "Buku Sudah Ditutup Pada Bulan dan Tahun Tersebut!" ,  "error" )
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: did you check error logs ?

Comment: If you get status 500, it means that an internal server error occurred. It's most likely some issue with our PHP-code. To find out the actual error message, make sure you have error reporting turned on (in PHP) and check your web servers error log for a more specific error message.

Comment: the request has no response data available

Comment: This loop ?? `foreach ($fetch1 as $fetch2) {}` does nothing other than loop to the end of a potentially large result set

Comment: I think you are trying to work out if this row already exists, but this query `$sql10 = "SELECT bulan_tutupBuku, tahun_tutupBuku FROM tutupBuku;";` will just return the whole table. You would be better to add a  WHERE clause using one or more of the parameters so you get either ONE or NO rows returned in the resultset

Comment: @RiggsFolly I use it to check whether the month has been used or not

Comment: The IF's after this line `foreach ($fetch1 as $fetch2) {}` Probably belong inside the `foreach()`

Comment: I have tried removing this syntax, but the result is still an error of 500
$ sql10 = "SELECT month_tutupBuku, tahun_tutupBuku FROM TutupBuku;";

Comment: This `if(empty($bulan) || empty($tahun) || empty($petugas)){` should really be the first thing you do in this Method, or better still before you call this method

Comment: can you give an example for the coding above so that the response I get is not 500? I have tried the advice that you gave remains the same. but the code runs on my localhost

Comment: thanks for your comment sir. this problem is fixed. myproblem in my table, the table name is "tutupbuku" not "tutupBuku" and i remove it $fetch1 = $statement1->fetchAll();